# Mouse Leave is not triggered correctly

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that expands on mousehover, and retracts on mouseleave, but in certain situations the button does not retract. I implemented a timer to avoid multiple triggers, but I was not successful, I tried to do it through css, but I had problems with synchronization between the animations.
It is possible to see this behavior through this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luismatheus/qde9rjcs/44/)

Is there any solution for this and why is this happening?

```js
options.forEach(option => { 
  option.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {

    let btnExpandable = event.target.childNodes[1];
    let optionsContainer = event.target.childNodes[3];

    if(!animated) {
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        btnExpandable.classList.add('btn--expandable-expand');
        optionsContainer.classList.add('options--expand');
        animated = false;
      },100);
               
    }
     animated = true;

  });

  option.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {

    let btnExpandable = event.target.childNodes[1];
    let optionsContainer = event.target.childNodes[3];

    if(!animated) {
    
       setTimeout(() => {
        btnExpandable.classList.remove('btn--expandable-expand');
        optionsContainer.classList.remove('options--expand');
        animated = false;
      },100);
                
    }
    
    animated = true;

  })  

})
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. Try putting  `animated = true;` right under `if (!animated) {`. So it only can change when the timeout was finished.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would help for you to elaborate on these "certain situations."

Comment: @wayneOS Did not work...